# (Luke 12:49) "I am come to send fire on the earth; and what will I, if it be already kindled?" translation

Tags: greek, luke

(Luke 12:49) "I am come to send fire on the earth; and what will I, if it be already kindled?"

Can it be translated: "I am come to send fire on the Earth. And what do I want? That it would be already kindled." or in a similar way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Greek of Luke 12:49 is:

> Πῦρ ἦλθον βαλεῖν ἐπὶ τὴν γῆν, καὶ τί θέλω εἰ ἤδη ἀνήφθη;

I would translate this (very literally) as:

**"Fire I came to cast upon the earth, and how I wish it were already kindled."**

The crucial word here is θέλω (theló), which means (BDAG #1)

**1. to have a desire for something, *wish to have, desire, want***

Compare the various translations:

- NIV: I have come to bring fire on the earth, and how I wish it were already kindled!
- BSB: I have come to ignite a fire on the earth, and how I wish it were already kindled!
- BLB: I came to cast fire upon the earth, and how I wish it were kindled already!
- NASB: I have come to cast fire upon the earth; and how I wish it were already kindled!
- NKJV: I came to send fire on the earth, and how I wish it were already kindled!
- CSB: I came to bring fire on the earth, and how I wish it were already set ablaze!
- ISV: I've come to set the earth on fire, and how I wish it were already ablaze!
- NET BIble: I have come to bring fire on the earth--and how I wish it were already kindled!

I do not see any interrogative (question) here in the grammar.